# AutoMapper: Breacking syntax issue from 4.x to 6.2

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

I've updated AutoMapper from 4.2.x to 6.2.0.

I'm getting some breaking syntax compiler errors:

```
this.CreateMap<ActDTO, Act>()
    .ConstructUsing((Func<AutoMapper.ResolutionContext, Act>)(ctx => new Act()))
    .ForMember(
    //...;
```

I'm getting this message:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Func<AutoMapper.ResolutionContext, Act>' 
    to 'System.Func<ActDTO, Act>'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is telling you what the problem is.  Your first type argument is wrong.  Why don't you simply remove the entire cast?